# In Factorio, how much fluid can a pipe transfer?

Tags: factorio

I've read that offshore pumps can pump at 1200 water per second. If I connect two offshore pumps will 2400 units? Or is 1200 the maximum?

Ideally I would like to run a single over pressure pipe into my nuclear hub to supply a few dozen heat exchanges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The throughput of a fluid pipe depends on the length of said pipe, but you can put in pumps to pressurize the pipe and increase the throughput.

There is a [handy table](https://wiki.factorio.com/Fluid_system#Transport) on the factorio wiki listing the throughput for different lengths of pipe between pumps.

Since heat exchangers consume 103.1 water each, a few dozen seems reasonable if you build the pipe with a pump every other grid square, which will give you a throughput of 6000 units. A pump every two blocks will only give 3000, and every three blocks gives only 2250.

Comment: Be aware that the factorio game engine reduces flow per pipe section, but an underground pipe (regardless of distance underground) counts only as the two end pipe sections. So best flow efficiency would be to create your longer pipe entirely using underground pipes, with the occasional pump between them.

Comment: Update: version .17 changed fluids so that each 'section' of pipe, no matter how long (how many pipe sections make up the 'section') are counted as one unit (and for purposes of calculating flow). A section, in this case, is any length of pipe sections ending in (connected to) a pump, factory, storage tank, or pipe intersection.

Comment: What is a "block"? I assume it's a tile distance, but how much?